# Subset of dataframe where two columns equals two lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple data frames with roughly 5 million rows in each.
Each data frame has two columns called `B` and `C`. Additionally I also have two lists of values where index 0 from the first list corresponds to index 0 in the second list.

What I need to do is get a subset of the full data frame, but where the values in both of the lists are tru for that specific index.

So basically:

```
df = 

A      B      C
------------------
val1   val2   val3
val4   val5   val6
val7   val8   val9


list1 = ["val2", "val8"]

list2 = ["val3", "val9"]
```

Then if I use this:

```
df.loc[(df['B'] == "val2") & (df['C'] == "val3")]
```

Then this will return:

```
df_new = 

A      B      C
------------------
val1   val2   val3
```

But I need it to do it for all the list items in `list1` and `list2`, so the resulting df should be:

```
df_new = 

A      B      C
------------------
val1   val2   val3 
val7   val8   val9
```

I was thinking about just creating a new column (`new_column`) and new list (`new_list`) where the two list names where joined, and then just run:

```
df[df['new_column'].isin(new_list)]
```

But I kind of worry that that is inefficient when taking into account I have to do this for roughly 5 million rows and a lot of different data frames.

So yeah, is there some neat trick to this ?

Comment: are the index a range index? or the column A is the index?

Comment: Nope, column A is not the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dataframe with the lists (list1 and list2) and merge the dataframe:

```
u = pd.DataFrame({"B":list1,"C":list2})
df.merge(u)
#[df.merge(u) for df in df_list] for list
```

---

```
      A     B     C
0  val1  val2  val3
1  val7  val8  val9
```

Comment: This will be the correct way ~ isin is not given the correct result ~ :-)

Comment: Ah, this is super sneaky. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The way to use `isin` , you need pass a `tuple` , in case the row match the production of two list

```
df[df[['B','C']].agg(tuple,1).isin(tuple(zip(list1,list2)))]
      A     B     C
0  val1  val2  val3
2  val7  val8  val9
```

Comment: I was playing around with this, longer but should be faster than `agg` :)  : `df[pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['B','C']]).isin(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((list1,list2)))]`